# Apply userprofile into a path

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-2000

I need to get a computer's user folder name and put it into a path, in this case startup and desktop path. I figured out how to find the user folder name, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to put that into a path. Anyone know how to?

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
```

It would be a great help.

EDIT

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
wscript.echo strPath
dim WSHShell, desktop, pathstring, startup, objFSO
set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WSHshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
desktop = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
pathstring = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(desktop)
WScript.Echo desktop
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
filesys.CopyFile "desktop", dolpis.vbs,"startup", dolpis.vbs
set objFso=createObject("scripting.fileSystemObject")
set objWShell=wScript.createObject("WScript.Shell")
usrName=objWShell.expandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")
if objFso.folderExists(strFolder) then
   objFso.copyFile strFileToCopy,strFolder&"\",True
else
   msgbox "The folder " & strFolder & " does not exist"
end if
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("C:\WINNT\system32\notepad.exe")
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Line 11 states "Object Required: Dolpis"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property of SpecialFolders of the WshShell object provides references to Windows special folders (Desktop, Favorites, etc ...)

List of Windows special folders available:

1. AllUsersDesktop
2. AllUsersStartMenu
3. AllUsersPrograms
4. AllUsersStartup
5. Desktop
6. Favorites
7. Fonts
8. MyDocuments
9. NetHood
10. PrintHood
11. Programs
12. Recent
13. SendTo
14. StartMenu
15. Startup
16. Templates

---

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wscript.echo "Desktop Folder = " & WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
wscript.echo "Startup Folder = " & WshShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")

For i = 0 to WshShell.SpecialFolders.Count -1 
     sf = sf & WshShell.SpecialFolders(i) & vbCr 
Next 
wscript.echo "Special folders of Windows : " & vbCrlf & vbCrlf & sf
```

***EDIT***

```
Option Explicit
Dim WshShell,Desktop,Startup
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Desktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
Startup = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
wscript.echo Desktop
wscript.echo Startup
```

Comment: Yes, but how would I apply this into a path? Am I just missing something?

Comment: @dolphin What did you mean apply into path ? explain more ! Did you mean that you want to set it as variable ?

Comment: I'll try to explain as best as I can. I want to make a variable for specialfolder desktop and startup, so the script can be used on any of my PCs. Sorry, I really don't know how to explain it more